# Regex issue with multiple results

Tags: php, regex, dom

I am doing some php html parsing and this is the code i have right now

```
function get_tag($htmlelement,$attr, $value, $xml ,$arr) {
    $attr = preg_quote($attr);
    $value = preg_quote($value);
    if($attr!='' && $value!='')
    {
    $tag_regex = '/<'.$htmlelement.'[^>]*'.$attr.'="'.$value.'">(.*?)<\\/'.$htmlelement.'>/si';
    preg_match($tag_regex,$xml,$matches);
    }
    else
    {
    $tag_regex = '/'.$htmlelement.'[^>]*"(.*?)\/'.$htmlelement.'/i';
    preg_match_all($tag_regex,$xml,$matches);
    }
    if($arr)
        return $matches;
    else 
        return $matches[1];
}
$htmlcontent = file_get_contents("doc.html");
$extract = get_tag('tbody','id', 'open', $htmlcontent,false);

$trows = get_tag('tr','', '', $htmlcontent,false);
```

The rows that has to be parsed/ the content in $extract can be viewed here http://pastebin.com/ydiAdiuC.

Basically, i am reading the html content and getting the tag tbody from the html. Now i want to take each tr and td values in the tbody and use it in my page. Any idea how to use, i think i am not using the right method of implementing preg_match_all.

Comment: Relevant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use PHP's [DOM Parsers](http://php.net/domdocument) for this. Not Regular Expressions.

A quick approach:

- *Load* in the HTML
- Get the `tbody` tag.
- Get the `tr` tags within.

Comment: Could you give me a short code? The html tags aren't closed proper and i have no control on the htmlcontent.

Comment: @joza: run [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) over it first in case it's totally broken. Otherwise tell DomDocument to ignore errors.

Comment: @joza, invalid markup will be an issue. See **hakre**'s comment for a way to get around this. Invalid markup would be a nightmare for regular expressions and one of the main reasons they have trouble parsing HTML.